# Create animation for all children

Tags: stylus

I'm attempting to create animations for all children of `.flow` where each one has an increasing delay. I expected the following code to work, but apparently interpolation is not support in property values.

```
for i in (1..6)
    .flow a:nth-child({i})
        animation 1s 0.{i}s fadeIn both
```

This code would work for the delay, but wouldn't work for the child selector.

```
for i in 0.1s 0.2s 0.3s 0.4s 0.5s 0.6s
    animation 1s {i}s fadeIn both
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `()`  in this case.

```
for i in (1..6)
  .flow a:nth-child({i})
    animation 1s (i / 10)s fadeIn both
```